# How Many Fragments Can I Host in an Activity?

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, android-activity

I am developing an application and was just curious about the best practice regarding how many fragments to host in an activity.

I have a view that I am going to reuse throughout my application, and I want to continue using it as much as possible to display various fragments. What is the recommended practice? Is it safe from an app performance standpoint to load unlimited fragments in an activity?

Comment: As many as it makes sense for your app. But it's not safe to load unlimited anything. You'll typically find less then 10 fragments in an activity (mostly because decomposing apps into even smaller pieces makes no sense)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the documentation i dont see a limits about how many fragment you can use, but... its good idea think before declare fragments, if you have a lot fragment you can start with problems about the "logic".

First start with Mockups, Wireframes and Navigation, then you should know how many fragments or activities you need.